# AngularJs: server side username and password validation

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angularjs and trying to write a code for login validation.following is my code to check whether the typed username and password are correct or not. How can I display "Invalid username" and "Invalid password" message when the username or password is not correct after pressing the login button?I want to display error messages instead of using alert.Thank you.

```
<script>
        var app=angular.module("app",[]);
        app.controller("MainCtrl",function($scope,$http,$window) {
        $scope.checkLogin = function(result) {
            //$http.get("login.jsp")
                          $http.get("login.jsp?sqlStr=select UsrNm,UsrPwd from dbo.tblUsr where UsrNm = '" + $scope.user_name + "'")
            .success(function(response) {
                $scope.myData = response;
                if(!angular.isObject($scope.myData[0]))
                                                alert("Invalid user name");

                else
                {
                    if($scope.myData[0].USRPWD!== $scope.password)
                        alert("Invalid password");
                    else
                        //alert("Successfully logged in");
                        $window.location.href = 'MainPage.html';
                }
            })
            .error(function(){
                alert("Resource not found");

            });
            };
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would work:

```
<script>
    var app=angular.module("app",[]);
    app.controller("MainCtrl",function($scope,$http,$window) {
    $scope.checkLogin = function(result) {
        //$http.get("login.jsp")
                      $http.get("login.jsp?sqlStr=select UsrNm,UsrPwd from dbo.tblUsr where UsrNm = '" + $scope.user_name + "'")
        .success(function(response) {
            $scope.myData = response;
            if(!angular.isObject($scope.myData[0]))
                                            alert("Invalid user name");

            else
            {
                if($scope.myData[0].USRPWD!== $scope.password)
                    alert("Invalid password");
                    $scope.hasError = true;
                    $scope.errorText = "Invalid Password";
                else
                    //alert("Successfully logged in");
                    $window.location.href = 'MainPage.html';
                    $scope.hasError = false;
                    $scope.errorText = "";
            }
        })
        .error(function(){
            alert("Resource not found");
            $scope.hasError = true;
        });
        };
    });
```

and in your html:

```
<div ng-show="hasError">{{errorText}}</div>
```

edit- this is really a bad way to validate passwords, as it looks like you're passing the password back from the server.  Don't do that, it's very, very insecure. You should validate with a hash on the server, and then just pass back an authorization or rejection to the client. Also, if you're transmitting passwords in plain text at any point, be sure you're using SSL.